# Is it possible to cast record to anonymous composite type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a table with a constraint that no two rows with coinciding value pair exists, the pair consists of an ordinary field value (`date`) and an expression (procured from the `json` field), like this:

```
create table
    test_table
        (
            date   date,
            json  jsonb,
            exclude (((date, json->>'item')) with =)
        )
```

Trying to create a table using the statement above gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "row" has pseudo-type record
```

OK, so I find a test case from postgres repo,

(https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/add5cf28d48149459466b9aff374d78aebf17482/src/test/regress/expected/create_index.out#L1337)

*(not exactly my case)*, but the solution is to type my row with a known type, for example like this:

```
create type my_adhoc_type as
    (
        a date,
        b text
    )
;

create table
    test_table
        (
            date   date,
            json  jsonb,
            exclude (((date, json->>'item')::my_adhoc_type) with =)
        )
;
```

This works, but seems a little bit cumbersome to define a persistent extra type every time, and unfortunately the type of the table itself does not play the trick as it is a pair of `(date, jsonb)`, not `(date, text)`.

It is possible to use `->` instead of `->>`, to extract `jsonb`, not `text` directly, but this solution does not seem ideal and breaks if I need to extract more than one field from json.

**So the question is:** is it possible to directly type my row with an appropriate anonymous type, something like:

```
            exclude (((date, json->>'item')::record(date,text)) with =)
```

Of course, a better solution to the initial problem will also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use an exclusion constraint here at all? Simple unique btree index is enough:

```
create unique index on test_table (date, (json->>'item'));
```

Comment: Tried to create unique index, but in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, got syntax error and stopped digging in this direction.

It turns out that postgres has different syntax for *unique table constraint* in `CREATE TABLE` and for *unique index* in `CREATE INDEX` statement.
First case, you can use only `column_name`s, not `expression`s, so that was the reason I got an error.
Example: `create table test_table (date date, json jsonb, unique (date, (json->>'item')))`.
Documentation on the statements corroborates this.

So my problem is solved, thank you!

Comment: Unique constraint definition in create/alter table follow SQL spec rules. But in the same time is limited by SQL spec. Some advanced features only exist for unique indexes - partial and expression indexes (there are no CREATE INDEX in the SQL standard).